# Reading JSON via Ajax without success

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a Node JS server, where I send JSON data from a MySQL database using this code:

```
app.get('/whatever/api/:IDmut', function(req, res) {
  var aquery = 'select * from mutations where id="' + req.param("IDmut") + '"';
  console.log(aquery);
  pool.query(aquery, function select(error, results) {
    res.send(JSON.stringify(results[0]));
  });
});
```

This JSON looks like this:

```
{"id":"SL2.50ch02_51010759_11","chr":"SL2.50ch02","pos":51010759,"ref":"T","ale":"A","g001":"0/0:39:99","g002":"0/0:34:99","g003":"0/0:33:99","g004":"0/0:37:99","g005":"0/0:33:99","g006":"0/0:35:99","g007":"0/0:27:99","g008":"0/0:33:99","g011":"0/0:35:99","g012":"0/0:22:85","g013":"0/0:34:99","g014":"0/0:32:99","g015":"0/0:39:99","g016":"0/0:31:99","g017":"0/0:47:99","g018":"0/0:36:99","g019":"0/0:26:97","g020":"0/0:33:99","g021":"0/0:25:94","g022":"0/0:28:99","g023":"0/0:35:99","g024":"0/0:38:99","g025":"0/0:13:58","g026":"0/0:35:99","g027":"0/0:41:99","g028":"0/0:34:99","g029":"0/0:37:99","g030":"0/0:24:91","g031":"0/0:46:99","g032":"0/0:42:99","g033":"0/0:35:99","g034":"0/0:34:99","g035":"0/0:42:99","g036":"0/0:41:99","g037":"0/0:21:82","g038":"0/0:34:99","g039":"0/0:36:99","g040":"0/0:31:99","g041":"0/0:31:99","g042":"0/0:34:99","g043":"0/0:34:99","g044":"0/0:42:99","g045":"0/0:34:99","g046":"0/0:24:91","g047":"0/0:40:99","g049":"0/0:32:99","g051":"0/0:20:79","g052":"0/0:34:99","g053":"0/0:40:99","g054":"0/0:51:99","g055":"0/0:41:99","g056":"0/0:33:99","g057":"0/0:28:99","g058":"0/0:21:82","g059":"0/0:37:99","g060":"0/0:29:99","g063":"0/0:36:99","g064":"0/0:25:94","g065":"0/0:26:97","g066":"0/0:17:70","g067":"0/0:27:99","g068":"0/0:35:99","g069":"0/0:36:99","g070":"0/0:28:99","g071":"0/0:30:99","g072":"0/0:14:61","g073":"0/1:17:99","g074":"0/0:17:70","g077":"0/0:29:99","g078":"0/0:42:99","g088":"0/0:18:73","g089":"0/0:26:97","g090":"0/0:40:99","g091":"0/0:29:99","g093":"0/0:37:99","g094":"0/0:26:97","g096":"0/0:28:99","g097":"0/0:41:99","g102":"0/0:33:99","g103":"0/0:19:76","g104":"0/0:19:76","g105":"0/0:27:99"}
```

In the clident side, I have the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    type:     "GET",
    url:      "the corresponding url... it is provate so...",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){alert(data);}
});
```

This does not work. No alert anywhere. However, if I change the url to `http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/anotherKey/anotherValue`, this works...

EDIT: I've just seen this error on the console:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)`

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'externalfile://' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.`

Comment: On the server side? Nope.

Comment: I mean on the client side

Comment: Use the dev tools in your browser to inspect the actual request and at least provide some troubleshooting information

Comment: Add to your $.ajax()
, error: function(err){ alert(err); }

Comment: Likely to be a cross-origin policy issue.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Look here at 401: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html, Also you are running this on a server I assume? Otherwise if not, you will have issues with cross-origin when doing an AJAX request.

Comment: Google the terms in that error ... will find plenty of results....also the term CORS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error you are getting it sounds like a CORS issue ([cross origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)). You are trying to make an HTTP request to a different server and the server is rejecting it because you don't have the correct access-control headers setup.

[This](https://github.com/troygoode/node-cors) is a good library for Node and Express that provides middleware that will add the headers.

Essentially what it boils down to is having the

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *
```

header on your response. This header will allow other domains to make requests to your web server. You can set specific white-listed URLs that are allowed to make requests or just a * that will allow any domains to make requests to your server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Notice: the only difference is that dataType is not "json", but "jsonp")

```
$.ajax({
    type:     "GET",
    url:      "the corresponding url... it is provate so...",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){alert(data);},
    error: function(err) {alert(err);}
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you should use res.json instead?

Comment: How can a question be an answer?  This is nothing more than a comment